# firefox is losing cookie

Tags: php, firefox

I am using firefox version 21.0. My site has login feature with remember me (cookie) option. Recently I have watched that even firefox has the same cookie values required for login and within expire date, firefox is not showing cookie values using $_COOKIE['key'] and thus remember me feature can not identify me as a remembered user of my website. I found sometimes it is working and sometimes missing.
I don't know why this is happening. Is it bug of that specific version?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a demo link ?

Comment: @stockBoi did you find the reason and solution for this? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, some users have disabled cookie. In order to enable them, see manual on the official website [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences). Most often, this is the problem.

Comment: I did not tell about other users of my website, I told about my firefox browser and it's cookie is not disabled. It can remember the login sometimes and sometimes it lost it's cookies automatically. I checked the firefox page info and found the cookies are still there (and not expired) but it is not showing from a php page using $_COOKIE variables. That's why even remember option is set on, it is unable to log into website automatically. If I use google chrome, there is no problem.